# Dell External SAS 5/E HBA and Hyper-V

Tags: linux, backup, virtualization, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, bacula

I have a Dell R710 running Win2008 R2 + Hyper-V with dual SAS 5/E HBA's. I'm building a Linux VM to install Bacula on and I need to connect it to my Dell PowerVault 124T via the SAS HBA. I've been doing some looking online and I have yet to find a straightforward answer on how to connect a SAS HBA to a VM, let alone a Linux VM. The flavor is Ubuntu 32-bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you are able to do this.

Hyper-V doesn't allow you to attach/map SCSI ports directly do devices, with the exception of phyisical disk (pass-though).

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to either user iscsi to connect to the TBU using raw scsi exporting (tgtd and ietd can support that IMO)
or use another hypervisor - KVM has a PCI Passthrough feature, VMWare ESX has the RDM (raw device mapping) feature